# Change jQuery click handler anchors within a loaded page

Tags: jquery

I have a master page that loads content into a div based on which link is clicked. I do this by using jQuery to add a click handler for certain anchors:

```
<div id="nav">
  <a href="somepage.html">
  ...
</div>

<div id="content"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav a, #footer a').click(function(e) {
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Some of the pages that get loaded into #content also have anchors for which I want to add a click handler (so the result of those clicks also go into #content). I've tried this:

```
$('#content a').click(function(e) {
  ...
});
```

but that doesn't appear to work. Any ideas how I can set the click handler on anchors in those loaded pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#content a', function(e) {
  ...
});
```

Should work. When you add elements dynaically you need to use `on()` to bind them to an event. From the docs:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to
>   .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform
>   event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in
>   the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the
>   page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML
>   is placed into the page.

Ideally you'd want a parent element closer in the DOM than `document`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, j08691. I added the .on() event handler using the '#content' element as suggested by Matt Burland.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#content').on("click", "a", function(e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the #content suggestion, Matt.